# Can't connect to "Secured Network" via WiFi. Get stuck at a Lock screen

Tags: wi-fi, connection-issues, oneplus-two, captive-portal

- OS: OxygenOS version 2.2.0
- Android version: 5.1.1
- Phone Model: ONE 2005 [OnePlus 2] (Build number: One A2005_14_151211)

When I connect to a Secured Wifi network that requires that I "Accept" some sort of agreement, normally I would click on "Sign into Wi-Fi Network", which pops up on my status screen and then I would "Accept" the agreement.

Now when I click on "Sign into Wi-Fi Network", all I see is a screen with a big circle around a lock. I can't tap on anything on this screen, except exiting out. If I exit out, I am taken back to my home screen and not connected to the internet. All that happens is that "Sign into Wi-Fi Network" appears in my status screen again. If I click on it again, I go right back to the lock screen.

Upon further investigation, I saw Option Dots on the top right on that screen with the big lock on it. I tapped the Option Dots, which brought up a menu with the following 2 options:

1. "Do not use this network"
2. "Use this network as is"

I selected "*Use this network as is*"

After doing this, I am taken back to my home screen as before. This time, the "Sign into Wi-Fi Network" option is no longer on my status screen and I am still not connected to the internet when I tried to access my email, Facebook, etc.

Any insight would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

SUCCESS! I did the same steps as I mentioned in the Edit to my Question:

1. Touch "Sign Wi-Fi Network
2. Touch the Option Dots
3. Touch "Use this network as is"

I then did 1 additional step:

4. Manually open a browser window (Chrome)

and SUCCESS!

5. Now I was given the screen where I was able to "Accept" the terms and log into the network. Internet for all Apps/items on my phone now worked.

Note: After this worked, I rebooted my phone and tried doing the above steps again to make sure this solution worked again and it does.